# Changing the background color of navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of navigation bar. Is it possible by using `background-color`? I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul id="login_signup">
        <li><a href="#login" id="login_link">Login <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="sign_link">SignUp <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is. Can you show your CSS?

Comment: @Valius79 its bootstrap

Comment: Why I asked for your CSS is because we need to see how you used it. Background color should work. .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top{background-color: #000;}. Also, where did you place that CSS. If it is called after bootstrap CSS, it will work.

Comment: I just tested with bootstrap3.3.7, and it looks like it has these declarations for the navbar***.navbar-inverse { background-color: #222; border-color: #080808;}*** . So, just overwrite that with your custom color, and place after bootstrap css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Simply do

```
.navbar-inverse{
  background-color:green;
}
```

Or whatever color you want it to be

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/g6L487jb/)

Answer (score 0):

try this css code:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

    <ul id="login_signup">
        <li><a href="#login" id="login_link">Login <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="sign_link">SignUp <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

or use this css also:

```
.navbar{background-color:#f1f1f1 !important;}
```